# Get month number from a date in javascript

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I have a daterangepicker function that is returning the selected date in this format 06 May 2016. What I am trying to do is extract the month as an integer, therefore from the above I should be able to return the number 5.

This is the line of code that returns the selected date - getDateString(new Date(opt.start)

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var date  = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
```

**The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.**

Comment: This worked as I was using the getDateString but I didnt need it thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
var datestring = getDateString(new Date(opt.start);
var monthNumber = new Date(datestring).getMonth()+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help since I am new in this field

```
var today = new Date();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "01";
month[1] = "02";
month[2] = "03";
month[3] = "04";
month[4] = "05";
month[5] = "06";
month[6] = "07";
month[7] = "08";
month[8] = "09";
month[9] = "10";
month[10] = "11";
month[11] = "12";

var monthNumber = month[today.getMonth()];

console.log("This month is " + monthNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, and more simple:

```
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
```

// Result, ie: January = 1 ... December = 12

```js
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
console.log("month", month);
```