# comparing only month in date string Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have two dates **Date1** and **Date2** in format **("Wed Apr 21 2020")** .I want to compare **only months** from two date strings.Forex ample **Date1="Fri Sep 13 2020"** and **Date2="Sun Feb 21 2020"** and now i want to compare September from DATE1 with February from DATE2 in such a way .

```
if(September>February){
  var X=greater
}else{
  var X=smaller
}
```

how can i achieve this in **JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get month number from a date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070273/get-month-number-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to extract the month from the string and get its index by using an array. See an example below:

```js
const Date1 = 'Fri Sep 13 2020';
const Date2 = 'Sun Feb 21 2020';
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const getMonthIndex = date => months.indexOf(date.split(' ')[1]);

if (getMonthIndex(Date1) > getMonthIndex(Date2)) {
    // var X=greater
    console.log('greater');
} else {
    // var X=smaller
    console.log('smaller');
}
```

Comment: thanks alot it helps :) .. i really appreciate your time